# What extensions are included in ArcGIS 10.2 Basic Version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I wanted to purchase ArcGIS 10.2. i used its trial version for last 2 month. now i am thinking to have Basic version. My work is based on Spatial analysis. so i dont need 3d and business analyst. for that i wanted know what extension will come with Arcgis 10.2 basic version.?. what are the functions available? and Spatial analyst extension come with ArcGis basic? or i have to purchase spatial analyst separately

if anyone have info about this plz tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools available for Spatial analyst do not depend on your licence level. You will have to buy the Spatial analyst extension apart from the main ArcGIS licence.

Note that you can find the differences between the licence levels [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis102-desktop-functionality-matrix.pdf)

Comment: ya ..thanks...so Spatial analyst is not come with main arcgis extension. i have to buy it separately right?